# PrestaShop how to show only color attribute

Tags: attributes, prestashop-1.7

I have to show in Home only the colors attributes. In product.tpl color and size on left, and on right a column with the radio input for other attributes.
(It's for display variants of a product)
How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is in templates/catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl
For example, for the Home, just take this code :

```
<div class="product-variants">
  {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
      {if !empty($group.attributes)}
      <div class="form-group product-variants-item">
          {if $group.group_type == 'color'}
          <div class="label">{$group.name}</div>
          <div class="clearfix">
          {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
              <label class="label-color">
                <input class="input-color d-none" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
                <span
                  {if $group_attribute.html_color_code}class="color" style="background-color: {$group_attribute.html_color_code}" {/if}
                  {if $group_attribute.texture}class="color texture" style="background-image: url({$group_attribute.texture})" {/if}
                ><span class="sr-only">{$group_attribute.name}</span></span>
              </label>
          {/foreach}
          </div>
          {/if}
    </div>
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
</div>
```

Change the class names on purpose.

You have another file to play with :
templates/catalog/_partials/variant-links.tpl